# Configure SSL certificate in JKS Format - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have created a keystore using following command

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

The I created CSR as follows,

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -certreq -alias client -keyalg rsa -file client.csr
```

Then I have signed that `csr` from https://getacert.com/signacert.html and added the `cer` to the keystore

```
keytool -import -keystore clientkeystore -file CARoot.cer -alias theCARoot
keytool -import -keystore clientkeystore -file client.cer -alias client
```

In my spring `application.properties` I have following configurations,

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=client
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-password=********
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:clientkeystore
```

I'm getting the following error when running the spring boot application

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:263) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:195) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.HttpsDemoApplication.main(HttpsDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:218) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:585) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain
    at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1136) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2019-08-08 16:35:53.004  INFO 21040 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-08-08 16:35:53.011  INFO 21040 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-08 16:35:53.014 ERROR 21040 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-08-08 16:35:53.017  INFO 21040 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

NOTE: once I remove properties from `application.properties` the application will start normally (there is no problem in the port)

Comment: Replace `server.ssl.key-password` with `server.ssl.key-store-password`

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thanks for the help, after changing property as you said the server get started but I' getting error `The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.` in the browser. I think it's some issue with the certificate signin. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: cheers happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check certificate format, some time format is not properly arrange. Open certificate in Notepad and check it properly arranged or not.if not arrange it properly and then try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).